# dask read_parquet with pyarrow memory blow up

Tags: dask, pyarrow, fastparquet

I am using dask to write and read parquet. I am writing using fastparquet engine and reading using pyarrow engine.
My worker has 1 gb of memory. With fastparquet the memory usage is fine, but when i switch to pyarrow, it just blows up and causes the worker to restart.
I have a reproducible example below which fails with pyarrow on a worker of 1gb memory limit.
In reality my dataset is much more bigger than this. The only reason of using pyarrow is it gives me speed boost while scanning compared to fastparquet(somewhere around 7x-8x)

dask : 0.17.1

pyarrow : 0.9.0.post1

fastparquet : 0.1.3

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

size = 9900000
tmpdir = '/tmp/test/outputParquet1'

d = {'a': np.random.normal(0, 0.3, size=size).cumsum() + 50,
    'b': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=size),
    'c': np.random.choice(['D', 'E', 'F'], size=size),
    'd': np.random.normal(0, 0.4, size=size).cumsum() + 50,
    'e': np.random.normal(0, 0.5, size=size).cumsum() + 50,
    'f': np.random.normal(0, 0.6, size=size).cumsum() + 50,
    'g': np.random.normal(0, 0.7, size=size).cumsum() + 50}
df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(d), 200)
df.to_parquet(tmpdir, compression='snappy', write_index=True, 
         engine='fastparquet')

#engine = 'pyarrow' #fails due to worker restart
engine = 'fastparquet' #works fine
df_partitioned = dd.read_parquet(tmpdir + "/*.parquet", engine=engine)
print(df_partitioned.count().compute())
df_partitioned.query("b=='A'").count().compute()
```

Edit: My original setup has spark jobs running that writes data parallely into partitions using fastparquet. So the metadata file is created in the innermost partition rather than the parent directory.Hence using glob paths instead of parent directory(fastparquet is much faster with parent directory read whereas pyarrow wins when scanning with glob path)

Comment: Do you get the same experience if you write with pyarrow? Note that when you write with fastparquet, you get a metadata file, so you can read from `tmpdir` without the glob part, and it should go faster.

Comment: Metadata file is an issue for me actually. The whole process works like this: partitions are written parallely using spark jobs. So the metadata file is created in the innermost partition, hence cant use parent directory to read all the data. Thats why using glob path(fastparquet is faster with parent directory load but with glob path load pyarrow wins hands down). Is there a way to read fastparquet without using metadata file in dask?

Comment: I tested different settings with varying partitions with the following results 1.Fastparquet is faster with parent directory path(needs metadata file though).  Memory usage is also fine. Slower with glob path read.                                                                     2.Pyarrow is faster with glob path read. Parent directory read is difficult because of schema mismatch(the column order is not same, easily fixed while writing df). Does cause high memory usage

Answer (score 1):

Some timing results on my non memory-restricted system

With your example data

```
In [17]: df_partitioned = dd.read_parquet(tmpdir, engine='fastparquet')

In [18]: %timeit df_partitioned.count().compute()
2.47 s ± 114 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [19]: df_partitioned = dd.read_parquet(tmpdir, engine='pyarrow')

In [20]: %timeit df_partitioned.count().compute()
1.93 s ± 96.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With columns `b` and `c` converted to categorical before writing

```
In [30]: df_partitioned = dd.read_parquet(tmpdir, engine='fastparquet')

In [31]: %timeit df_partitioned.count().compute()
1.25 s ± 83.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [32]: df_partitioned = dd.read_parquet(tmpdir, engine='pyarrow')

In [33]: %timeit df_partitioned.count().compute()
1.82 s ± 63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With fastparquet direct, single-threaded

```
In [36]: %timeit fastparquet.ParquetFile(tmpdir).to_pandas().count()
1.82 s ± 19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With 20 partitions instead of 200 (fastparquet, categories)

```
In [42]: %timeit df_partitioned.count().compute()
863 ms ± 78.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: My prod data is really huge, size is about 50000000 rows with 17 columns. I cant use the parent directory to load data(mentioned above), hence have to make do with glob path read.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend selecting the columns you need in the `read_parquet` call

```
df = dd.read_parquet('/path/to/*.parquet', engine='pyarrow', columns=['b'])
```

This will allow you to efficiently read only a few columns that you need rather than all of the columns at once.

Comment: I do need all the columns I store. But is this a normal behaviour? My production environment has worker nodes configured with 5gb limit. Fastparquet uses at max 3gb whereas pyarrow just blows through that

Comment: You might try limiting the memory or number of threads of workers. I don't know how well the memory footprint of arrow has been determined. The dataframe is 1.6GB big, so actually you are using too many partitions in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could also filter as you load the data.e.g by a specific column
`df = dd.read_parquet('/path/to/*.parquet', engine='fastparquet', filters=[(COLUMN, 'operation', 'SOME_VALUE')])`.

Imagine operations like `==`, `>`, `<`, and so on.